# Is there any downside to selecting the IIS 'Require Server Name Indication' https binding setting by default?

Tags: iis

I've been trying to get my head around the IIS 'Require Server Name Indication' https binding setting.

We have a few web sites that have it set and a few that don't but no reason why one should have it but not another.#

It seems there are only benefits to using it so does it not make sense just to set it regardless?

Comment: No need to bother with it. SNI is a feature that allows multiple websites to share the same IP address and port, while using different SSL certificates for each site. This is useful when you have limited IP addresses or want to host multiple secure sites on the same server. SNI is a great solution for shared IPs, but there is one small remaining disadvantage; it only affects a very small proportion of internet users – those who use legacy browsers or operating systems. Refer to: https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-server-name-indication.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother yourself now. SNI based bindings are there for a decade now and you should use them for almost all sites by default,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

You want an IP based binding only when you really need it (as a fall back but rarely required now).